# JQuery, PHP: Better handling javascript returned by ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimization

I am working on a web application completely based on ajax. There are two main sections. The left panel have links; and the contents of right panel are dynamically loaded via ajax when any link is clicked. The ajax call returns json encoded response that contains both the html and javascript. Here is the sample page1.php file.

```
$output=array();

ob_start();
include("page1html.php");
$output['html']=ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
include("page1script.php"); //page1script.php return the page specific script
$output['script']=ob_get_clean();

echo json_encode($output);
```

Here is sample page1script.php

```
<script>
    ajaxscript = {   //namespace
        init: function () {
        },
        foo: function () {
        }
    };
</script>
```

The same style is for other pages, but with different html and differnet script. (Thats why I have not created a global js file, because it will become a big file.. I want only page specific js to be loaded).

```
//this is onclick of link
updatecontents("page1.php");  ...
updatecontents("page2.php"); and so on
```

Here is my js

```
var xhr;
var ajaxscript = null;

function updatecontents(addrs) {
    if(xhr) xhr.abort();
    $('#mainpanel').html('<div class="loader"></div>');
    $('#ajscript').html('');
    ajaxscript = {};    //remove the previous functions in the namespace; This is where I cleanup the old functions

    xhr=$.ajax({
        url: addrs,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.html)
                $('#mainpanel').html(response.html);
            if(response.script)
                $('#ajscript').html(response.script);

            if(typeof(ajaxscript.init)=='function') ajaxscript.init();
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
}
```

This is the best I I could acheive... But I just noticed a growing list in firefox firebug scripts tab: under js//eval/seq/ , that grows every time I click a link. This makes me feel like the scripts are loading into memory everytime I click a link, and they stay in browser cache. I want to get some expert opinion if I am on the right path.. or what optimizations do I need.

Answer (score 0):

i have nearly the same problem. for me it is, I can not navigate links when i refresh div. have. i think you must use .load instead html in your ajax-success

Answer (score 0):

Using .load instead of .ajax to load content is a good solution. Data will be cached in the browser. However, when the result(including html and js) is big, perhaps js content will block the html content. So my advice is, why don't write js content into a file in PHP,and return just the URL of that js file.